# Pre-play, interim-play, intra-play communication games

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, game-theory, bayesian-game

I have a question that seems easy but I want some clarification. Suppose that we have a communication Bayesian game. The game starts when the players learn their prior infornation and after this they start to communicate. Is this type of communication called pre-play or interim-play? Or the preposition "pre" deals only with the fact that the players communicate only before their actions? Also, the term "intra-play" is something that occurs in games with communication?

Comment: I personally would call this pre-play. "Play" in my head is the actually taking actions, while private information is intrinsic to a player, regardless of his/her participation in the game.

Comment: @WalrasianAuctioneer Ok, in essence since the communication is before they decide what stratefy to play in the game, it is pre-play communication. And if for instance this game was repeated and in any new stage then it would also be intra-play or mid-play, right?

Comment: In terms of pure terminology, I would say so, personally.

Comment: Yes! Terminology is the only thing that matters...